# Xamarin studio 5.7 won't run after installation

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I installed the Xamarin studio for windows which is a bundle of MonoDevelop and GTK#. I double click and nothing happens.

First thing, [this](http://pastebin.com/tsGy1H4w) is the log from the IDE.

Second thing, [Bug 10558](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10558) Is the same problem but unfortunately post dates back to 2013 which about version 4.0. The fix they mentioned which is updated `MonoDevelop.Core.dll` file did not work.

3rd thing, GTK# bin directory is added to the environment variable, a couple of posts on the internet says that something wrong with "Win32 DLL search path", unfortunately no steps to help.

4th thing, I tried Xamarin universal installer but I press continue and nothing happens.

Update: I have Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with .NET Framework 4.0 installed.

Update 2: It used to work with me before. I don't know what has changed after I formatted my PC few months ago. I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#alternate_search_order_for_desktop_applications) link on [Bug 10558](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10558) which might be helpful but I did not understand it. Also found [this](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commit/ad672ce79a50ce844398ae30cce8005163e41d0e) patch which I didn't know how to apply it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the Windows version you use? If you don't have .NET 4.5 installed, I think it can be the cause.

Comment: Windows 7 Pro 64-bit. No it is .NET 4.0

Comment: Lex Li has the answer. Xamarin Studio 5.7 requires .NET 4.5. Older versions of Xamarin Studio (e.g. 5.0) did use .NET 4.0 but more recent versions do not. What is interesting is that the installer did not indicate that you did not have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: @MattWard, so it is still an issue of the installer.

Comment: Oops, did not see that coming :D I thought that you meant having 4.5 installed is the problem, my bad :D . I will uninstall 4.0 and install 4.5.

Comment: @LexLi It works! Looks like its time to say good bye for visual studio :D I appreciate it if you put it as an answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you meet, is a typical one when running binaries compiled against .NET 4.5 on a .NET 4.0 only system.

Microsoft did move some key types between assemblies, which led to such exceptions, and there is no way to fix that except upgrading your system to .NET 4.5.

For Xamarin/Mono guys, they should modify the installer to inform end users about this change. They should also update web pages, such as this MonoDevelop page, which still says 4.0 is enough (no, 4.5 is required),

http://www.monodevelop.com/download/